# Create a custom page to use in all the sites, A multisite question

Tags: multi-language

I have been developing [www.americaeb5visa.com](http://www.americaeb5visa.com) .
This is a multilangual site, It was very difficult for me to figure how to create multilangual site out, I found the solution by using a plugin called Multilingual Press. It works nicely, sometimes it gives difficulties though.

I created a custom page in one of the languages at the site, this is the link: [Custom Page](http://www.americaeb5visa.com/fr/votre-aller-simple-pour-les-etats-unis/) . I want to add this page in all the languages, I was wondering If I can create the HTML file of the page and upload it to the server and from each language do the necessary changes.

I hope question was clear, looking for help. 
Thank you.

Comment: the actual content of the page its just the image?

Comment: There is an image on top and more content below